# How do I remove part of the number from psql query return?

Tags: python, database, psql

The following are query results are from two different tables in the same database, both id columns are integer. How should I remove the number 16789 from the first table id to match the second id?

news=> select id from log limit 10;

### id

1678923
 1678924
 1678925
 1678926
 1678927
 1678928
 1678929
 1678930
 1678931
 1678932
(10 rows)

news=> select id from articles limit 10;

### id

23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 30
 29
(8 rows)

Answer (score 0):

How about subtraction?

```
select id - 1678900 from log limit 10;
```

This might stop working if you have over 100 ids, depending on how the articles table maps to the log table.

Comment: It does not work in this context. as I need to join the two tables in order to sort through the title from the articles table.     news=> select articles.title,count(*) as num
    from articles,log where
    articles.id = log.id-1678900
    group by title
order by num desc

Comment: I'm confused as to why that wouldn't work.  Is it that you want the last two digits regardless of what the leading digits are?

Answer (score 0):

In the database:

SELECT
 TRIM (
 LEADING '16789'
 FROM 1678929
 CAST (news AS TEXT)
 ); -- 29

Comment: don't understand, would you mind give a little explaination?